# Footnotemark and footnotetext - wrong number

Tags: footnotes

I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}
% serve (forse insieme a graphicx) per aggiungere freccia e testo/equazione sopra segno uguale =
\usepackage{mathtools}
% serve per plottare freccia grande, vuota, ruotata (vedi file: quadrato con frecce)

\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{\mathclap{#1}\\[0.5ex]\displaystyle\uparrow\\ ~}}{ = } }
%serve per aggiungere testo sopra segno uguale =


\title{\textbf{Elementi di Calcolo delle Probabilità}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  %serve per stampare il titolo ed eventualmente altro

Ecco del testo\footnote{Ecco una nota al testo.}

\begin{align}
P(R_2 | B_1) &= \left( 1 - P(R_1 | R_2) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)}
\eqstackrel{P(B | A) = P(B) \quad \text{rel. 126 a pag. 49}}
\\
&= \left( 1 - P(R_1) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)} \\
&= P(R_2)
\eqstackrel{\text{per hp\footnotemark}}
\\
&= \frac{R}{R + B}
\end{align}
\footnotetext{aaa}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that the footnote has a wrong number; in particular the previous footnote has the number 1, instead the footnote introduced by footmark has the number 4. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should put a *complete* MWE, with the `\documentclass`, the `\usepackage` used, etc. so that we could compile directly...

Comment: Hello @F.Pantigny thank you

Comment: Not related: You should use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` instead of `\left(` and `\right)` in your case.

Comment: Hi @F.Pantigny what is the difference?

Comment: In mathematical notations, when brackets are nested within other brackets, the surrounding brackets must be bigger. Here with `\left(` and `\right)`, the exterior brackets have the same size as the interior ones. For a good mathematical notation, you have to fix the sizes of the brackets 'by hand'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is `\mathclap`. I suggest not using `\mathclap` (but `\clap`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{
\clap{$\scriptstyle #1$}\\[0.5ex]\displaystyle\uparrow\\ ~}}{ = } }

\begin{document}
Ecco del testo\footnote{Ecco una nota al testo.}

\begin{align}
P(R_2 | B_1) &= \left( 1 - P(R_1 | R_2) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)}
\eqstackrel{P(B | A) = P(B) \quad \text{rel. 126 a pag. 49}}
\\
&= \left( 1 - P(R_1) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)} \\
&= P(R_2)
\eqstackrel{\text{per hp\footnotemark}}
\\
&= \frac{R}{R + B}
\end{align}
\footnotetext{aaa}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

---

Since you have loaded `footnote`, I suggest to put the `{align}` in a `{savenotes}` and use `\footnote` directly. However, the command `\footnote` must not be put in the command `\text` but just after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\eqstackrel}[1]{\stackrel{\substack{
\clap{$\scriptstyle #1$}\\[0.5ex]\displaystyle\uparrow\\ ~}}{ = } }

\begin{document}
Ecco del testo\footnote{Ecco una nota al testo.}

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{align}
P(R_2 | B_1) &= \left( 1 - P(R_1 | R_2) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)}
\eqstackrel{P(B | A) = P(B) \quad \text{rel. 126 a pag. 49}}
\\
&= \left( 1 - P(R_1) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)} \\
&= P(R_2)
\eqstackrel{\text{per hp}\footnote{aaa}}
\\
&= \frac{R}{R + B}
\end{align}
\end{savenotes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your precious help

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer to the question but, since the OP searches a way to add explanations to a calculus, I will suggest to use `{DispWithArrows}` of `witharrows`. The footnotes are correctly extracted (by use of the package `footnote` or, if you prefer, `footnotehyper`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[footnote]{witharrows}


\begin{document}
Ecco del testo\footnote{Ecco una nota al testo.}

\begin{DispWithArrows}[fleqn,displaystyle]
P(R_2 | B_1) &= \left( 1 - P(R_1 | R_2) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)}
\Arrow{$P(B | A) = P(B)$ \\ rel. 126 a pag. 49}
\\
&= \left( 1 - P(R_1) \right) \frac{P(R_2)}{1 - P(R_1)} \\
&= P(R_2)
\Arrow{per hp\footnote{aaa}}
\\
&= \frac{R}{R + B}
\end{DispWithArrows}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I like this alternative

Comment: F.Pantigny is there a way to get the same result but with a single number on the right side?

Comment: In `nicematrix`, you have a environment `{WithArrows}` which is similar to `{aligned}` of `amsmath`. That environment may be inserted in an environment `{equation}` and you will have only one number.

Comment: The solution with \usepackage[footnote]{witharrows} has the drawback that you should compile two times the code in order to see the arrows correctly (I tested it in Texmaker)

Comment: You are right. However, you won't have to compile twice if you only do a modification of another part of your document. Moreover, there is tools such as `latexmk` which do the right number of compilations directly. For instance, Overleaf uses `latexmk` (afaik).